# inward vs. inside, when to use which?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

I have an old car with manually adjustable mirrors.  As I was driving home with a friend, I wanted him to adjust the mirror for me so that I could see more of the street. I ended up not asking because I wasn't sure about how to say it because I don't understand the difference between 'inward' and 'to the inside'.

This is the sentence I originally wanted to say :

> Could you change the mirror more to the inside?

Is this right and does it sound natural?

I looked up the definition of the words and to me, it makes sense to use *to the inside/inward* interchangeably in most contexts since 'to' indicates a direction and inside a 'surface'. So you move an object towards/to the inside of another object, e.g. to the inside of the enclosed case where the mirror is situated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

> inward

to describe movement towards the *inside* of *something*, and

> inside

to describe the area that is being contained.

> Please move the mirror *inward*.
>   *please move the mirror towards the car*
>
> Please move the mirror to the *inside*.
>   *please move the mirror towards the inside of the car*

both mean the same if the assumption is the center of the car is *inside* the line of vision.

Comment: Thank you!  What about when I want someone to turn their wrists inward/outward when doing a specific exercise in the gym?  Could I say turn your wrist to the outside at the end of the movement?

Comment: You can use either "to the outside" or "outward", and probably will want to show them also.

Answer (score 2):

Simple physics dictates that in order to view more of the street from the driver's seat of an automobile, you must *increase,* and not decrease, the angle of incidence of reflected light as it strikes the mirror on its way to the driver's eyes.

This means that the mirror must be swiveled *away* from, not *toward* the driver. The mirror must be adjusted ***outward***, not *inward.*

Say:

> *"Can you adjust the mirror **outward**?"*

A native speaker will understand that you mean

> *"Can you adjust the mirror (so that it reflects further) **outward**?"*

---

<kbd><sub><sub>WARNING: STATEMENTS IN THIS ANSWER ARE SMARTER THAN THEY APPEAR</sub></sub></kbd>

Comment: Thank you! Maybe I should have said that I wanted to see a portion of the street that is next to the car, e.g. when parking you can see the curb. But yes, you are right, to see more of the entire street it should be adjusted outward!